# Export Comments from Powerpoint for Mac 2011 using VBA

Tags: macos, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to export reviewer comments (Insert->Comment) from a Powerpoint for Mac 2011 presentation.  I have tried an export roughly based on the example VBA code here: 
[Extracting comments from a PowerPoint presentation using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342902/extracting-comments-from-a-powerpoint-presentation-using-vba)

However it appears that the Mac version of VBA doesn't recognizes the type "comment". The code fails here:

```
Dim oCom As Comment <-- Error: "User Defined Type Not Defined"
```

Are there any other ideas/work arounds on how to export these reviewer comments?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not near the Mac to test this, but it may use the older style comments as in PPT versions prior to 2002, I think it was.  Try iterating through the shapes collection checking the .Type of each shape. If the .Type = msoComment ( = 4 ) then it's a comment.

Comment: Just tested this on the Mac.  It seems that the Comment object type and the Comments collection aren't exposed to the OM, although the comments ARE the "new-style" comments, same as in Windows versions (and not comment-type shapes as in earlier versions of PPT).  I hope to be alive to celebrate the completion of Mac Office, but don't hold out a great deal of hope.  FWIW, I'll report this to MS.