# Extracting All Comments from PPT Slide using VBA

Tags: macos, vba, powerpoint

During the research I found below link,

[Extracting comments from a PowerPoint presentation using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342902/extracting-comments-from-a-powerpoint-presentation-using-vba)

Below is the solution provided in for thissame type of question.

```
Sub ConvertComments()
''# Converts new-style comments to old

    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSlides As Slides
    Dim oCom As Comment
    Dim oShape As Shape


    Open "filename.txt" For Output As 1
    Set oSlides = ActivePresentation.Slides

    Dim myContext As String
    For Each oSl In oSlides
        For Each oCom In oSl.Comments
            myContext = ""
            For ShapeIndex = oCom.Parent.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
                myContext = myContext & oCom.Parent.Shapes(ShapeIndex).AlternativeText & " "
            Next
            Write #1, oCom.Author & ";" & myContext & ";" & oCom.Text
        Next oCom
    Next oSl
    Close 1
End Sub
```

I found that this script not fetching the reply comments in the slides, Its only fetching the main comments from the slides, I also tried to update this solution to get all comments from the slide, bad luck I couldn't find the solution.

Comment: The code you posted apparently began life on my site. That's fine, but it no longer does what the original did (convert comments from new to old style) so to avoid confusion, you might want to change the name of the subroutine and remove the comment line below it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that will show each comment on slide 1 and under it, the number of replies to the comment, the author and text of each reply:

```
Sub Example()

    Dim oCom As Comment
    Dim x As Long

    For Each oCom In ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Comments
        With oCom
            Debug.Print .Author & vbCrLf & vbTab & .Text
            Debug.Print .Replies.Count
            For x = 1 To .Replies.Count
                With .Replies(x)
                    Debug.Print vbTab & .Author & vbTab & .Text
                End With
            Next
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

This works in 2016; I'm not sure of 2013 and I know it won't work in 2010 (and earlier) because it doesn't have the ability to enter replies to comments.  Replies entered in 2016 get converted to multiple comments.